# Zoomlevel 19 in Leaflet = grey tiles

Tags: leaflet, zooming

When I use the latest `Leaflet`, or even the beta, `Leaflet` just displays grey area.

I have gone through the logs on my webserver, and `Leaflet` doesn't even try to load any x19 tile.

```
var lagx1 = L.tileLayer('https://myserver.org/tiles/x1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {detectRetina:false, id: 'mapbox.light', attribution: attribution});
```

Using Google, it seems to have been a problem since before version 1.00.

Does anyone have a fix or a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet should have a fixed height of the map html element, otherwise he doesn't know how many tiles to display. If I remember, google is a layer displayed over the tile layer using a tricky hack. So maybe consider setting like 200px to the height of the map html element.